# Netbeans php Xdebug Socket Exception with Joomla debugging

Tags: php, netbeans, joomla, xdebug

My system

```
PHP Version 5.4.0-1build1~ppa1~oneiric
Xdebug v2.2.0rc1, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by Derick Rethans
Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu)
```

When I debug a Joomla up, coming near to the error that I wish to spot on, debugger breaks and gives me Socket Exception problem, with follownig stack trace.

Please help me, I am going crazy.

I was not able to downgrade xdebug, and I have tried on my machine with - another browser, 
- another Java build, 
- a new userdir for netbeans ( deleting completely the older one  , 
- recreating the project putting also the netbeans directory under another path ( this because I needed to put files under www-data properties)

```
 INFO [org.netbeans.modules.php.dbgp.DebugSession]
java.net.SocketException: Pipe interrotta
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:141)
at org.netbeans.modules.php.dbgp.packets.DbgpCommand.send(DbgpCommand.java:90)
at org.netbeans.modules.php.dbgp.DebugSession.sendCommands(DebugSession.java:211)
 [catch] at org.netbeans.modules.php.dbgp.DebugSession.run(DebugSession.java:143)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few bugs in the Xdebug 2.2.0RC1 release with debugging. Those should all be fixed with yesterday's release of Xdebug 2.2.0. If you can still reproduce it, please file bug reports at http://bugs.xdebug.org.

Comment: Yes I have tried upgrading to 2.2 stable version but it continues not working. I think anyway is something related with my system that I can found.

Even in xedbug log there is something about an error!

Comment: "Something about an error" -- that's not very useful. What is the error in there?

Comment: Hi Derick sorry I typed wrong. In xdebug log There was not anything about an error, so I supposed that the problem was in mine apache architecture, some params maybe or some misconfiguration.
I have reinstalled all my ubuntu system and now works correctly with php 5.3.12. Thanks for support

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all following:
- remove all watches ( ooops I did not have any one ! )
- use a new fresh userdir with netbeans but nothing
- upgrade xdebug to 2.2.0
- downgrade php version to 5.3.10 ( but I was not able )
- reinstall completely apache and LAMP ( but some configuration were not completely deleted, so if you want to do it, be sure of purging and configuration file of apache or php related )

At the end I did a fresh ubuntu installation, and now it works fine.

Hope error log in xdebug can improve to take in account and solve this kind of error without uninstalling all!